# Invalid because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause

Tags: sql

I would like to create a query that gets a product from the product table, it's type and category from the type table and the count of songs on the product.
But somehow this query throws an error. It started when I added `count(n.name)`

```
SELECT p.name, p.publisher, p.description, p.price, p.picture
     , p.releasedate, t.type, t.category, count(n.name) AS songs
  FROM Products p
 INNER JOIN ProductType t ON (p.type_id = t.id)
 INNER JOIN Songs n ON (p.id = n.product_id)
```

The error I get is

> Column 'Products.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group only `Songs` rows, then join the aggregated data instead of the `Songs` table proper:

```
SELECT p.name, p.publisher, p.description, p.price, p.picture
     , p.releasedate, t.type, t.category, n.songs
  FROM Products p
 INNER JOIN ProductType t ON (p.type_id = t.id)
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
     product_id,
     COUNT(n.name) AS songs
   FROM Songs
   GROUP BY product_id
 ) n ON (p.id = n.product_id)
```

That way you'll avoid adding almost all your output columns to the `GROUP BY` clause, which you would have to do in the query posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, p.publisher, p.description, p.price, p.picture, p.releasedate, t.type, t.category, count(1) AS songs
                    FROM Products p
                    INNER JOIN ProductType t ON (p.type_id = t.id)
                    INNER JOIN Songs n ON (p.id = n.product_id)
GROUP BY p.name, p.publisher, p.description, p.price, p.picture, p.releasedate, t.type, t.category
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation to *why* he needs GROUP BY would be in place?

Comment: Now I get 'Te text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.'

Comment: Ok, you need a group by because you have an aggregate function in the SELECT clause.

Comment: which fields are ntxet, text or image datatypes?